# Using python requests to open multiple tabs while maintaining session cookies

Tags: python, python-requests

I am attempting to use **requests** to obtain information from a website. The problem is that this website requires a homepage to open in one tab, while the information you need is open in another. If I close that homepage, the page I need no longer keeps my login session. How could I imitate having two tabs open to prevent this issue. Example:

```
session = requests.Session()

payload = {'username':'username_here','password':'password_here'}

webSession = session.post("http://website.com/login", data=payload)
webSession2 = session.get("https://website.com/home/home-page")
webSession3 = session.get("https://website.com/Reports/1234")
```

**webSession** returns <Response [200]>

**webSession2** also returns <Response [200]>, implying my login was successful.

**webSession3** returns <Response [401]>, implying I'm no longer logged in.

How can I get webSession3 to return the information I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already creating a `Session` object. Use it to get cookies after your first request (probably homepage in your case).

```py
cookies = session.cookies.get_dict()
```

Now pass cookies in your subsequent request(s):

```py
response = session.post("https://website.com/Reports/1234", cookies=cookies)
```

Comment: This should work for normal websites, but if OP correctly described the requirement (having homepage opened in other tab), there's likely some weird stuff going on =)

Comment: Yup probably they should use selenium if this doesn't solve this doesn't work out. I'm wondering if that's just a bug/bad development looking like a security feature.

Comment: The company that developed the website has a bit of reputation for doing things in ways that don't make sense. This solution worked on other examples, but not this specific site. As @ScriptKiddieOnAComputer menitioned, Selenium was ultimately my solution. I appreciate the help!